# Decoupling UI and Controllers in a nested custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What I think I want to do is completely isolate each step of a wizard into a custom element directive.

I think this would allow me to completely encapsulate the detail of each page of the wizard. For example:

```
<custom-wizard-tag>
    <enter-name-page page="1" name-placeholder="name"/>
    <enter-address-page page="2" name-placeholder="name" address-placeholder="address" last-page/>
</custom-wizard-tag>
```

So far, so good. Each of the elements above has its own directive, and each of these specifies a templateUrl and a controller (templateUrl could be supplied as an attribute, of course).

I want each page of the wizard to 'inherit' some behaviour. The UI components would contain the buttons, which would need to query the outer scope, for example to determine whether it is possible to move forward, backward and so on. We would also need to call member functions on the parent scope in order to actually move the wizard forwards and backwards, and to check whether the current page number matches 'ours'.

I'm new to this so bear with me...

I read the documentation on `directive`, and thought I could use `scope: { onNext: '&onNext' }` in order to 'inherit' the `onNext` function from the previous scope (which is assumed to be one which is 'wizard-like'). However, this is not what angular seems to do. It seems to want map the inner scope's `onNext` via an attribute called `on-next`, thus breaking encapsulation, because now the UI elements must reference functions in the parent scope - which is exactly what I wanted to avoid.

Am I barking up the wrong tree, or is there an idiomatic way to do this. A day of web searching has not got me far, but I could be using the wrong search terms.

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: You still need to pass in the parent controllers function something like : on-next="onNext" and in the directive call it like scope.onNext()(argument);

Comment: @vodich is there not a clean way to avoid that? I want to couple the controllers' interfaces, to each other, not the controllers to the UI elements, at least in the overall wizard definition.

Comment: So you want that the child "enter-address-page" directive would have access to the parent (wizard-tag) properties/functions?

Comment: @RichardHodges well you are coupling directives to controller, other way may be that you use events to do what you need of the top of my head

Comment: Will the [Delegate pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) match what u are achieving? Maybe we can try set the scope's delegate to another scope, then do something like `scope.delegate.foo()`? And we may somehow declare what kind of methods must  get implemented by the `delegate` scope.

Comment: @MMhunter I'll look into it. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

`scope: { onNext: '&onNext' }`
won't do any inherintance, you would have to define `onNext` in the template (the template scope) the same way you do with the `page` property: `<enter-name-page page="1"`

If you have a function `onNext` defined in you `customWizardTag` directive either in `link` function or in its controller, you'll have to put it in the controller, because the controller can be passed to the child directive. Then you'll be able to pass the parent directive's controller in the link functions of `somethingPage` directives.

```
.directive('parentDirective, function() {
    return {
        controller: someControllerThatHasOnNext,
    }
 })

.directive('childDirective', function() {
    return {
        require: '^^parentDirective',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, theParentDirectivesController){
            theParentDirectivesController.onNext();
        }
    }
})
```

If this is what you wanted

Comment: Thanks Adam. I think that's exactly what I want. So the 4th argument to the link function is the parent controller? This starts to make more sense.

Comment: Yes, you can get more info in angular docs -> directives -> Creating Directives that Communicate

Comment: Actually, it is any controller that is somehow linked to the directive. Either a parent or its own I think. The require will get you a controller, one "^" means own, if exist, otherwise it look on parents. "^^" means only parent's.